# Is there a way to add a link to the "Tool" section of CQ5

Tags: aem, sling

I am trying to find if there is a way to add a link to an external application in the "Tools" section of CQ5. The external link would be going to one of the applications we have running on our enterprise. The link would simply titled "Sample App" and pointing to "//intranet/some/app"

This is how the "Tools" section looks right now:

[image]

Comment: The tools section of CQ5 comes from /libs/cq/core/content/tools I think you can override this from the apps. i.e. CQ overrides libs path with the apps one.

Answer (score 0):

- Use the [Resource Resolver tool](http://instance.domain/system/console/jcrresolver?msg=JcrNodeResource%2C%20type%3Dcq%3APage%2C%20superType%3Dnull%2C%20path%3D%2Flibs%2Fcq%2Fcore%2Fcontent%2Ftools&test=%2Ftools.html) to convert urls to resources. => `/libs/cq/core/content/tools`
- From the resource, use CRX-DE to determine components that render it => `/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/admin/page`
- Override/overlay that component by converting `/libs/` to `/apps/` and change as much or as little as you need.  In this case, probably `body.jsp`

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional node under /libs/cq/core/content/tools/jcr:content/content/items/tools/cq

set the resource type of the node as "cq/gui/components/projects/admin/toolitem"
and set a "link" property pointing to your external tool.

Refer to an existing node under path /libs/cq/core/content/tools/jcr:content/content/items/tools/cq